# Удалить из линейного списка целых чисел первый отрицательный элемент

Tags: алгоритм, указатели, pascal

Написать программу, которая удаляет из линейного списка входной последовательности целых чисел первый отрицательный элемент. вроде что-то написал, она выдаёт 1 отрицательный элемент, но не удаляет его из списка, не могу понять почему, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
program laba8;
Type T=^TABL;
     TABL=record;
           D: integer;
           L:T;
          End;
var
  k,F,W:T;
  M,N,i :integer;
begin
  write('Количество элементов =');
  readln(N);
  F:=nil;
  for i:=1 to N do
    begin
      New(W);
      Read(W^.D);
      W^.L:= F;
      F:= W;
   end;
  W:= F;
  for i:=1 to N do
    begin
      if W^.D<0 then begin
                     M:=W^.D;
                     end;
      W:= W^.L;
    end;
   writeln;
  writeln('Первый отрицательный элемент = ',M);
   W:= F;
  Writeln('Вывод списка');
 for i:=1 to N-1 do
    Begin
      Write (F^.D,' ');
      F:= F^.L;
   end;
   dispose(W);
   W:=nil;
 readln;
end.
```

Comment: @Victor1995, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А не подскажете ли место, где у Вас должно быть это самое удаление. Я его в упор не вижу. И при удалении желательно список не рвать, поэтому храните ещё указатель на предыдущий элемент, чтобы туда поместить ссылку на следующий за первым отрицательным.